# Powershell Google Sheets API with service account, how do I set scopes?

Tags: powershell, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

I have a Google Sheet I want to fill using Google Cloud service account. So I've created the account, shared the sheet with it. I activate it with:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=XXX.json
```

and I put this in my powershell code:

```
$cred = gcloud auth print-access-token
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $cred"} -Uri 
$requestUri -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $data
```

but I keep getting this error:

> @{code=403; message=Request had insufficient authentication scopes.; status=PERMISSION_DENIED}

so my question is, where and how do I set scopes for service account?

Comment: how are you creating your access token ($cred) using a service account?  I would love to see the code for this.

Comment: Have you seen [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#permissions) on setting up and using the service accounts?

Comment: @dalmto, there is no additional code.

Comment: @AMolina , I went through that already. I might be missing something so I'll read it once more. What I know I don't understand is how the specific Google Sheet is assigned to GCP project. OK, I've shared it with a GCP service account, and also assigned the GCP project to the Script/Resources/"Google Platform project..." . Doe I need to do the latter even if I'm not using script at all?

Comment: How about [this guide](https://lazyadmin.nl/it/connect-to-google-api-with-powershell/)? The sheet itself does not get attached to the project, you access the sheet with the API and the "usage" of the API is what's attached to GCP, that's what you need the credentials for. When you use an Apps Script for example, the script itself is attached to the GCP project, but not the Sheets, Docs or other files it accesses, only the services (through the scopes) are related at all.

Comment: @AMolina, I have it working for months using my google account. It's just I'm not sure how to implement the serviceaccount auth. "gcloud auth print-access-token" gives me the access token.

Comment: [This article](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account) explains how to do it, you grant the scopes by enabling the APIs in the GCP Console, then the credentials will be attached to that. [This article](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/) offers a broader overview of working with authorization.

Comment: @AMolina, thanx for helping, but I've already done all of that as I wrote the powershell script to be used with my work account. All APIs have already been enabled in order for enable access for my account.

Comment: Could you give more information what you try to do? If you look at scopes from user and service account token they are basically the same so I don't think it's an issue with your script. Make sure you have Cloud API enabled in the resources you try to access.